# Focus doesn't work after I changed the default border with javascript

Tags: jquery, css, focus

Basically I have a form. Above the form I have a link that anchors to the form. When someone clicks the anchor, it changes the form inputs' css's to give it a red border. I also set a timer to restore the original border color after a few secs. The thing is, after all this process happens, when someone clicks an input, the :focus doesn't work anymore. (The :focus used to give the border a darker color). I'm using jQuery by the way.

How can I avoid this to happen? I want the :focus to happen normally even after the anchor is applied. Here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/LSpm8/ and here is the code:

**JS**

```
$("#anchor").click(
    function () {
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
        $("#form input").css({
            'border': '1px solid red'
        });
        $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
            $("#form input").css({
                'border': '1px solid #CCC'
            });
        }, this), 1800));
    }
);
```

**CSS**

```
input { border: 1px solid #CCC; }
input:focus { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#form" id="anchor">Link</a>
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **!important** like so it should fix your problem:

```
input:focus { border: 1px solid #000!important; }
```

This will prevent jQuery from over writing it inline. Here is a fiddle of it - http://jsfiddle.net/yasEB/

Answer (score 1):

When jquery applies a style it is inserted inline. Essentially preventing any stylesheets from affecting the element. Try just clearing the border `border: ''`.

http://jsfiddle.net/LSpm8/1/

```
$("#anchor").click(
    function () {
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
        $("#form input").css({
            'border': '1px solid red'
        });
        $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
            $("#form input").css({
                'border': ''
            });
        }, this), 1800));
    }
);
```